# RPI CrossCompiler Environment setup Error

Tags: raspberry-pi, environment-variables, cross-compiling

When I try to set up an environment for Raspberry Pi on Linux Ubuntu 13.4 machine(Cross Compilation) it gives following error

bash: export: `/home/ganesh/RPICComp/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-': not a valid identifier

I have stored my tool master folder in /home/ganesh/RPICComp/
and Kernel version is 3.18.y

I am using following command for setting up the Environment

export CCPREFIX= /home/ganesh/RPICComp/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-

What would be the possible Error?

I am doing as per this link http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation 
(Instead of Folder "tools" its tools-master for the kernel which I have downloaded )

Kindly Guide Me

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> export CCPREFIX=
>   /home/ganesh/RPICComp/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-

Remove the space between CCPREFIX= and /home....